# How to enforce an object to be virtually inherited from?

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, type-traits, virtual-inheritance

Is it possible to define a base class for which it is only possible to inherit from virtually? That is, can we fill in the dots in

```
struct Base {
    static_assert (..., "You may only inherit virtually from Base");
};
```

such that

```
struct A : public virtual Base {};
```

compiles fine, but

```
struct B : public Base {};
```

does not? Of course, `Base` can't possibly know all types that will inherit from it, but we may naively attempt to use CRTP here:

```
#include <type_traits>

template <typename taBase, typename taDerived>
struct VirtualBase : public taDerived, public virtual taBase {};

template <typename taDerived>
struct NonVirtualBase : public taDerived {};

template <typename T, typename U>
struct IsVirtualBaseOf : std::integral_constant <bool, 
    std::is_base_of <T, U>::value && 
    sizeof(NonVirtualBase <U>) == sizeof (VirtualBase <T, U>)
> {};

template <typename taDerived>
struct Base {
    static_assert (IsVirtualBaseOf <Base <taDerived>, taDerived>::value, "");
};

struct A : public virtual Base <A> {};
struct B : public Base <B> {};
```

This will not work, because when `Base` is instantiated, `A <Base>` and `B <Base>` are still incomplete types and inheriting from them in `VirtualBase` and `NonVirtualBase` therefore yields a compiler error. (Also, the `std::is_base_of` won't work for the same reason)

Of course, we may move the `static_assert` to `A` and `B`, but as these resemble, to be defined, client classes I would like to enforce the virtual inheritance through the definition of `Base`. Maybe there's a way to delay the validation until `A` and `B` are no longer incomplete types by wrapping `Base` or maybe this could be achieved using C++ concepts. Any suggestions are welcome. Thanks in advance.

Side note: the ability to forward declare the inheritance intent for an object, without defining it yet, would be very welcome now, don't you agree? E.g.

```
struct X {};

struct Y : public X;

struct Y : public X {};
```

**Edit:**

Although this question is indeed a duplicate, I believe to be able elaborate a bit to arrive at a solution that works for my use case. It's not an answer to this question though. As pointed out by peterchen in the comment section, the inheritance hierarchy is known to further derived classes and this is pivotal to solve the problem in my situation.

First, let me explain the use case a bit further. `Base` is usually a `struct` carrying the NonConstructible concept by inheriting from a `Traits` base.

```
struct Traits {
private:
    Traits ();
};
```

A desire for uniformity arises as we would like all traits classes to be non-constructible, but still be defined types. To this end, we may agree to inherit from `Traits`. Different use cases may call for overriding (by hiding) different elements of the traits class `Base`. For instance,

```
struct Base {
    typedef int SocketIdType;
    typedef short PortType;
    typedef char IpAddressType[4];
};

struct SpecialSocketIdTraits : public Base {
    typedef unsigned int SocketIdType;
};

struct SpecialPortTraits : public Base {
    typedef unsigned short PortType;
};

template <typename> struct Socket;

typedef Socket <SpecialSocketIdTraits> Socket1;
typedef Socket <SpecialPortTraits> Socket2;
```

Oftentimes, the need arises to combine these independently overriden traits classes. We therefore introduce a utility `MergeTraits` struct.

```
template <typename... taTraits>
struct MergeTraits : public taTraits... {};
```

We would like this to enable us to do the following in general:

```
typedef MergeTraits <SpecialPortTraits, SpecialSocketIdTraits> SpecialSocketIdAndPortTraits;
typedef Socket <SpecialSocketIdAndPortTraits> Socket3;
```

However, since both traits classes have `::SocketIdType` for instance, the lookup is ambiguous. Contemplating on the situation at hand reveals that having virtual inheritance in the hierarchy by default would solve the ambiguities but would also satisfy your expectations. Since `Base` would only be inherited from once, and `SpecialSocketIdTraits` would hide `::SocketIdType` from `Base` we're guaranteed to have `SpecialSocketIdAndPortTraits::SocketIdType` equal to `unsigned int`. If there is however another such

```
struct SpecialSocketIdTraits2 : public virtual Base {
    typedef long SocketIdType;
};
```

Then, the look-up of `::SocketIdType` through `MergeTraits <SpecialSocketIdTraits, SpecialSocketIdTraits2>` would be correctly ambiguous again. Now for the solution, inspired by the comment of peterchen. We can examine the pack `taTraits` for the presence of structs inheriting from specific base traits. These inheritances can then be verified to be virtual.

```
template <typename...> struct Tuple;

template <typename, typename> struct ShouldMaybeVirtualInheritFrom;

template <typename B>
struct ShouldMaybeVirtualInheritFrom <Tuple <>, B> : std::true_type
{};

template <typename D, typename B>
struct ShouldMaybeVirtualInheritFrom <Tuple <D>, B> :
    std::integral_constant <bool,
        !std::is_base_of <B, D>::value || IsVirtualBaseOf <B, D>::value
    >
{};

template <typename D, typename... Ds, typename B>
struct ShouldMaybeVirtualInheritFrom <Tuple <D, Ds...>, B> :
    std::integral_constant <bool,
        (!std::is_base_of <B, D>::value || IsVirtualBaseOf <B, D>::value) &&
        ShouldMaybeVirtualInheritFrom <Tuple <Ds...>, B>::value
    >
{};
```

The real solution in my code is a bit more complicated and utilizes some of the already existing template metaprogramming facilities as syntactic sugar, but this is what it boils down to. We can now use this component in our `MergeTraits` to detect virtual inheritance from `Base`.

```
template <typename... taTraits>
struct MergeTraits : public taTraits... {
    static_assert (ShouldMaybeVirtualInheritFrom <Tuple <taTraits...>, Base>::value,
    "For all traits T in taTraits...: if T inherits from Base it should do so virtually.");
};
```

The disadvantage being that we need to pollute `MergeTraits` with a list of these asserts, of course. However, we can delegate the checks to further derived classes, solving my problem at least.

```
template <typename... taTraits>
struct MergeTraits : public taTraits... {};

template <typename... taTraits>
struct MergeFromBase : public MergeTraits <taTraits...> {
    static_assert (ShouldMaybeVirtualInheritFrom <Tuple <taTraits...>, Base>::value,
    "For all traits T in taTraits...: if T inherits from Base it should do so virtually.");
};
```

Comment: If you have `class base{}; class a : public base{}; class b : public base{}; class final : public a, public b {}`, it might be easier to trigger on the ambigous `static_cast<base const &>(final())`. However, I couldn't figure out a way to enforce this check in the most derived class. ---- generally, I'm a strong advocate of  `// only virtually inherit from this class, or Igor will come after your family.` as this is a sufficient solution in many cases. Interesting "puzzle" nontheless. Out of curiosity, what is the use case?